# Content Query Web Part. How do I get the "ItemStyle" name in the xlst?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have adapted my Content Query Web Part (CQWP) so it generates "ul" tags instead of "table" tags. It uses a custom "ContentQueryMain.xls" and a custom "ItemStyle.xsl".

I would like to add my ItemStyle as a cssclass to the opening tag of my "ul" tag. So the html looks like this.

```
>     >  <ul class="CustomItemStyle">
>     >     <li> --HTML content goes here-- </li>
>     >     <li> --HTML content goes here-- </li>   </ul>
```

The opening tag is generated by the (custom) "ContentQueryMain.xls". Does anybody know how I can access the ItemStyle value in the "ContentQueryMain.xls"?

Thanks,
W0ut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer myself.

In the "ContentQueryMain.xls" you can select the itemStyle by using this xslt

```
    <xsl:variable name="FooBar" select="$Rows[1]/@Style" />  
    The selected ItemStyle: <xsl:value-of select="$FooBar" />
```

Note:  to avoid exceptions you probably want to include a test to see if the $Rows variable contains any results / data. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for perfect solution. But - what if there are no rows - but you still want to see what style they would've been? i.e. To tell which web part is 'calling' the xslt assuming you're using the same xslt file for different cqwp's.